# Is it possible to have more than 1 Role with 1 service account in different namespaces with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rbac

Is it possible to have more than one role bind to a single service account?

Comment: TL;DR yes, [it's possible](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#aggregated-clusterroles). Did you tried? have you faced any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible to have multiple `RoleBindings` / `ClusterRoleBindings` that link `Roles` / `ClusterRoles` to single `ServiceAccount`.

You should remember that permissions are **additive** - you can add another `Role` /  `ClusterRole` to `ServiceAccount` to extend its permissions.

---

I've created simple example to illustrate you how it works.

First I created `red` and `blue` `Namespaces` and `test-sa` `ServiceAccount`:

```
$ kubectl create namespace red
namespace/red created
$ kubectl create namespace blue
namespace/blue created
$ kubectl create serviceaccount test-sa
serviceaccount/test-sa created
```

By default, the newly created `test-sa` `ServiceAccount` doesn't have any permissions:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n red --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
no
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n blue --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
no
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n default --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
no
```

Next I created two `pod-reader-red` and `pod-reader-blue` `Roles` that have permissions to get `Pods` in `red` and `blue` `Namespaces` accordingly:

```
$ kubectl create role pod-reader-red --verb=get --resource=pods -n red
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/pod-reader-red created
$ kubectl create role pod-reader-blue --verb=get --resource=pods -n blue
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/pod-reader-blue created
```

And then using `RoleBinding` I linked this `Roles` to `test-sa` `ServiceAccount`:

```
$ kubectl create rolebinding pod-reader-red --role=pod-reader-red --serviceaccount=default:test-sa -n red
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/pod-reader-red created
$ kubectl create rolebinding pod-reader-blue --role=pod-reader-blue --serviceaccount=default:test-sa -n blue
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/pod-reader-blue created
```

Finally we can check that `test-sa` `ServiceAccount` has permission to get `Pods` in `red` `Namespace` using `pod-reader-red` `Role`
and `test-sa` `ServiceAccount` has permission to get `Pods` in `blue` `Namespace` using `pod-reader-blue` `Role`:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n red --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n blue --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n default --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
no
```

Comment: yes it does.
@matt_j thanks for such an informative answer